# If 1 is the identity of the multiplicative (semi)group what is the term for 0?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

Broadly given an operator $*$ the term identity is used for an element $e$ such that $x * e = x$ for all elements.  However is there a term for a value $ x * O = O$ for all values? This was brought to mind by this question [What is the identity in the power set of $\Sigma^*$ as a monoid?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3732114/what-is-the-identity-in-the-power-set-of-sigma-as-a-monoid) that shows that the empty language has this property under concatenation. False has this property under the and operator.

Comment: Can such an element $O$ exist necessarily?

Comment: If you are in a *semigroup*, though, an element $0$ such that $x0 = 0x = 0$ for all $x$ is called, perhaps unsurprisingly, a “zero element”. However, you can’t have zero elements in nontrivial monoids or groups. Note that your two examples are semigroups.

Comment: Thanks I've changed that.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin What makes you say you can't have a zero element in a nontrivial monoid? Consider for example the set $\Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ of nonnegative integers with binary operation given by multiplication. This operation is clearly associative, and $x\cdot 1 = 1\cdot x = x$ for all $x\in\Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, but $0\cdot x = x\cdot 0 = 0$ for all $x$ as well. In fact, given any ring $R,$ $R$ is a monoid under multiplication, and will be a nontrivial monoid with $0$ element so long as $R$ itself is a nontrivial ring.

Comment: @Stahl: A momentary moment of silliness. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excepting the special case of a group with only one element, groups cannot have $0$ as an element, and multiplication as its operation, as it is required that every element have an inverse, and what is the multiplicative inverse of $0$?

It sounds like you are interested in Rings.

Rings take a set with two binary operations, one operation is analogous to addition and the other is analogous to multiplication.  A ring has an additive identity ($0$) and an multiplicative identity ($1$) and requires that multiplication distribute over addition.  As consequence $a\cdot 0 = 0.$

(Yes, there is also the special case here, where the ring has one element.)

Rings have a generalization of $0$, which is called an "ideal."  An ideal is a subset of the ring such that for every element in the ideal multiplied by a member of the ring gives an element in the ideal.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such element in a nontrivial group.  **Every** element of a group has an inverse.

Let $G$ be a group and suppose (for purpose of contradiction) $G$ contains your proposed element $O \neq e$.  Then there is a $p = O^{-1} \in G$ such that $pO = e \neq O$.  But this contradicts the definition of $O$.  Therefore, there is no nontrivial group, $G$, containing an $O \neq e$ as described.

Another way to get at this, using the required existence of inverses, is that from
$$  x O = O  \text{,}  $$
we have
$$  x = xO O^{-1} = O O^{-1} = e  \text{.}  $$
So the assumed multiplication properties of $O$ are incompatible with its membership in a group *unless* the only element of the group is $e$ (in which case $e = O$ does satisfy the properties of both the multiplicative identity in a multiplicative group and the properties of the $O$ element you describe).  (This is why I wrote "$O \neq e$" in the second paragraph: to avoid the case that we were secretly only talking about the group with one element.)

Comment: Shouldn’t your first line say, There’s no such element in a ‘nontrivial’ group

Comment: @JacFrall : Ah, yes.  Thanks!  Fixed.